# Google Chrome install errors

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, google-chrome, debian, kali

Ok I have browsed all the other google chrome install things but all them have not helped me. Most say `sudo apt-get install -f` or `sudo apt-get -f install` But that does not work for me. I get the following spew:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 179 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 310642 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing google-chrome-stable (56.0.2924.87-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-8) ...
```

and when I try to install chrome I get this:

```
(Reading database ... 310642 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (56.0.2924.87-1) over (56.0.2924.87-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-8) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: For multiline outputs, please select text and use the `{}` button in the editor rather than using `\``.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the message says the problem is `google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however: Package libappindicator1 is not installed.` Normally, `sudo apt-get -f install` is how'd you fix this, but since that's not working for you, you can manually fix it with `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before installing chrome?

if so install libappindicator1 first such as `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1` then install chrome.